# set of positive definite matrices are the interior of set of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I'm studying a book and encountered with that: the set of positive definite matrices are the interior of set of positive semidefinite matrices.

What is the norm here?

Answer (score 0):

One can take the Frobenius norm
$$
||A||^2=\langle A,A\rangle=Tr(AA^T),
$$
see the article [Properties of positive (semi)definite matrices](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-306-47819-2%2F1.pdf).
Example $B5$ is the statement you have mentioned, on page $239$.

Comment: Here, interior point mean relative interior?